# Facing issue to connect from web job( in Azure app service) to SQL server (On Premises)

Tags: connection-string, azure-webjobs, entityspaces

On local it works fine. In Azure gives the error as Server not found or network specific instance not found.

We have 2 connection strings in app.config file.

1. One connection string is in `<appsettings>` section
2. Another connection string is under `<Entityspaces>` which is third party tool we are using.-

`

```
 <Entityspaces>
     <connectioninfo>
      <conenctions>
        <add name="" proivdermetadatekey=""> etc
      </conenctions>
     </connectioninfo>
    </Entityspaces>
```

`

The connection string in apsetting  is working fine. Connection string which is in another section entityspaces is giving issue

Comment: can you connect to your on-premise SQL Server from the public internet?

Comment: No. We dont connect it from public network